# How do I stop unsolicited tweets?

Tags: twitter

I'm getting Tweets in Arabic from someone I'm not following. They aren't retweets.

I don't really want to click on them, and they are making me uncomfortable. How do I stop them?

Answer (score 1):

From [5 Ways to Kill Twitter Spam](http://www.socialmediaexaminer.com/5-ways-to-kill-twitter-spam/), in particular,

> #### Block Unwanted Contacts
>
> By systematically blocking obvious spammers, you’ll keep your social media environment easy to use.
>
> You can easily block people on Twitter and remove their ability to send you direct messages.

looks like a single click on **block** should suffice.